# Cisco ASA - What are the advantages of ESP-NULL (Null Encryption)

Tags: windows, vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, ipsec

What are the advantages of using a ESP-NULL transform-set in the Cisco ASA.  From my understanding the transform-set parameters are only used during phase1 negotiation.  The packets are still encrypted according to the phase2 SA (crypto isakmp policy XXX) and thus you still incur a lot of the overhead when actually transfering data.  The only thing I can see ESP-NULL speeding up is the phase1 negotiation.

Am i correct or am I misunderstanding transform-set vs isakmp policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed mixing things up.

ISAKMP policy refers to parameters used in phase 1&2, i.e. how you authenticate the peer and how you encrypt the ISAKMP conversation.

Transform-set refers to what is actually used to encrypt and authenticate the data (i.e. how you *transform* the data).

So ESP-NULL in a transform-set means that you are not encrypting your data.

The only scenario (apart from testing/troubleshooting) where you would use ESP-NULL is when you want to use AH for authentication but have no need for encryption.